# Finding the length

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

How to determine the length of PR?
[image]

We can determine the angle **QSP** and the length $SR$ then what to do?

Comment: Hint: since $\Delta SQR$ is an isosceles, Pythagoras's th. suffices to deduce the length of its sides. We then have a right triangle in $\Delta SQP$ with a known angle and a known side.

Comment: Can't I use , $\frac{QS}{\sin 70^0} =\frac{PQ}{\sin 90^0} $?

Comment: Yes, yes we can (although finding $PS$ directly might be easier).

Comment: The easy way I'm seeking because I dont know the value $\sin 70^0$ bcz I'm not allowed to use calculator.

Comment: So this is homework?

Comment: Keeping in mind Polya's definition of geometry as correct reasoning on incorrect figures, it's nonetheless worth noting that the angle labeled as $20^\circ$ looks more like the $70^\circ$ angle of $OPS$.

Answer (score 0):

Compute $|SR|$ by relating $\cos(45^\circ)$ to $|QR|=2$ and $|RS|$.

Notice that $|QS|=|SR|$ (why?) and then compute $|PS|$ by relating $\tan(20^\circ)$ to $|PS|$ and $|QS|$.

Comment: I can not use the calculator. Angle **QPS** is $70^0$ so I intended to use $\frac{length}{\sin x} =\frac{length}{\sin y}$

Comment: I don't think you can express $\tan(20^\circ)$ in terms of radicals, and so $|PS|$ cannot be expressed in terms of radicals. If your answer has to be exact, you must include $\tan(20^\circ)$ in the final expression.

Comment: Because angle P is $70^0$ then can't  we use $\frac{QS}{\sin 70^0} =\frac{PQ}{\sin 90^0}$ in the **PQS** triangle. Then putting, $\sin 70^0= \frac{QS}{PQ}$?